# How can I make Perl's File::Find faster?

Tags: performance, perl, file-find

I have a folder named *Lib* and I am using the File::Find module to search that folder in whole dir say, `D:\`. It's taking a long time to search, say even 5 mins if the drive has a lot of subdirectories. How can I search that Lib faster so it will be done in seconds?

My code looks like this:

```
    find( \&Lib_files, $dir);
    sub Lib_files
    {
       return unless -d;
      if ($_=~m/^([L|l]ib(.*))/)
      {
          print"$_";
      }
      return;
    }
```

Comment: Please post code that you have actually compiled and run.

Comment: Why is this DOWNVOTED?! I am facing the same issue. `File::Find` is very slow.

Comment: Make sure that a background task isn't running under Windows Task Scheduler. That was my biggest problem when Perl was taking 5 minutes to list a directory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Searching the file system without a preexisting index is IO bound. Otherwise, products ranging from [`locate`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?locate+1) to [Windows Desktop Search](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/default.mspx) would not exist.

Type `D:\> dir /b/s > directory.lst` and observe how long it takes for that command to run. You should not expect to beat that without indexing files first.

One major improvement you can make is to print less often. A minor improvement is not to use capturing parentheses if you are not going to capture:

```
my @dirs;

sub Lib_files {
   return unless -d $File::Find::name; 
   if ( /^[Ll]ib/ ) {
        push @dirs, $File::Find::name;
   }
   return;
}
```

On my system, a simple script using `File::Find` to print the names of all subdirectories under my home directory with about 150,000 files takes a few minutes to run compared to `dir %HOME% /ad/b/s > dir.lst` which completes in about 20 seconds.

I would be inclined to use:

```
use File::Basename;

my @dirs = grep { fileparse($_) =~ /^[Ll]ib/ }
           split /\n/,  `dir %HOME% /ad/b/s`;
```

which completed in under 15 seconds on my system.

If there is a chance there is some other `dir.exe` in `%PATH%`, `cmd.exe`'s built-in `dir` will not be invoked. You can use `qx! cmd.exe /c dir %HOME% /ad/b/s !` to make sure that the right `dir` is invoked.

Comment: +1 for not using capturing parentheses - but on the whole, it is likely to be a second-order effect compared to disk access time.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Yeah, I should correct how I phrased that because the most important savings will come from not printing so often. However, it will be hard to beat `qx'dir d:\ /ad/b/s'` for this kind of thing.

Comment: Don't you mean `/[Ll]ib/`? `[L|l]` is (roughly) equivalent to `(?:L|\||l)`, not `(?:L|l)`.

Comment: @Robert P: My mistake illustrates well the perils of copy & paste without thinking. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Hi can u give me the exact code because the above code displays "file not found" when i executed

Comment: @lokesh That is the exact code I ran. **You** need to **replace** `%HOME%` with whatever directory you are trying to search.

Comment: hi...am getting the result " File not found " when i run the script

use File::Basename; 
my @dirs = grep { fileparse($_) =~ /^[L|l]ib/ } 
           split /\n/,  `dir e:\\/ad/b/s`; 
print @dirs;

what may be the prob?

Answer (score -1):

how about not using File::Find module

```
use Cwd;
sub find{
    my ($wdir) = shift;
    my ($sdir) = &cwd; 
    chdir($wdir) or die "Unable to enter dir $wdir:$!\n";
    opendir(DIR, ".") or die "Unable to open $wdir:$!\n";
    foreach my $name (readdir(DIR) ){
        next if ($name eq ".");
        next if ($name eq "..");
        if (-d $name){
            &find($name);
            next;
        }

        print $name ."\n";
        chdir($sdir) or die "Unable to change to dir $sdir:$!\n";
    }
    closedir(DIR);
}
&find(".");
```

Comment: One way to optimise this would be to store each directory name in a local variable so that you can close the directory handle before recursing. The example given, unfortunately, holds the each directory handle open as it inspects sub-directories and if you have a very deep path you could be starving your system of handles.

Comment: **1)** Don't use `&` to invoke subs unless you know why. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html **2)** `$name =~ /^\.\.?\z/` is perfectly fine. **3)** Did you time your code? Why do you think this would be faster?

Comment: let me tell you why 1) & is for historical reason. In the old times, I wrote it like that.! 2) I just want to use string comparison and not regex, what's your problem? 3) Did you time mine? 4) because its not calling the find module but using Perl's internal construct. Reasonable?