# How do I find all lib directories under a Windows path?

Tags: perl

I am getting the result "File not found " when I run the script:

```
use File::Basename; 

my @dirs = grep { fileparse($_) =~ /^[L|l]ib/ } 

split /\n/, dir e:\\/ad/b/s; 

print @dirs;
```

This is my actual code. I am trying to `grep` the directories and subdirectories which have the name *lib* or *Lib* in the whole drive.

Comment: Er, what does the second line do?

Comment: this line : split /\n/, dir e:\\/ad/b/s;  <-- is your problem. why don't you use glob instead to find files starting with [lL]ib ?

Comment: please show your actual code.  you seem to be missing some parts there

Comment: this is my actual code... am trying to grep the directories which have the name lib or Lib in the whole drive.am not worried about the files present.i want only the directories named as lib or Lib in the whole drive including subdirectories.

Comment: @lokesh, suppose dir e:\\/ad/b/s is actually  `dir e:\\/ad/b/s`, this code of yours should have worked like you expected, unless there're no direcotries named Lib or lib on Drive E.

Comment: @all, somehow the backquotes get automatically lost :(

Comment: This is where the code is coming from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783631/how-can-i-make-perls-filefind-faster/1783662#1783662

Comment: Mike: Yes, it should have been `\`dir e:\\/ad/b/s\``

Comment: @lokesh The code you posted **CANNOT** be the code you are running: `syntax error at t.pl line 5, near "dir e:" Substitution replacement not terminated at t.pl line 7.`

Comment: This is getting a bit rude. You repeatedly ask for help when you don't even bother to get compiling code. We do expect that you are going to be the person to do the most work on your own behalf, so show some respect for us by at least posing a good, thoughtful question with compiling code to show that you are at least trying.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the code from [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783631/how-can-i-make-perls-filefind-faster/1783662#1783662), the only thing I can think of is that there might be some external `dir.exe` on your path that does not understand the commandline options for `cmd.exe`'s built-in `dir`. For example, with Cygwin's directories in my path, I get

```
dir: cannot access /ad/b/s: No such file or directory
```

**You** should also get in the habit of showing the ***exact*** output you are getting if you want people to be *able to* help you more effectively.

To make sure that does not happen, use:

```
use strict; use warnings;

use File::Basename;

my @dirs = grep { fileparse($_) =~ /^[Ll]ib/ }
           split /\n/,  `cmd.exe /c dir e:\\ /ad/b/s`;

print "$_\n" for @dirs;
```

Note the backticks **`` `**. Note also the correction to the pattern you are using.

Comment: @Sinan, I assume @lokesh is a Windows XP user. I tested the code he borrowed from you and it worked without anything funny. So now I'm thinking he's using some other system.

Comment: @Mike: I am on Windows XP. When I put `c:\opt\cygwin\bin` in the path, `No such file or directory` is the message I get because Cygwin's `dir.exe` thinks `/ad/b/s` is a path. (It is perfectly OK with `E:\ `). So, @lokesh must have some other `dir` in the path. The solution is to explicitly invoke `cmd.exe`s built-in dir that understands the options that are passed to it.

Comment: @Sinan, your explantion makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Any number of things.

- I hope you're using backticks that are getting lost in your post:
- But you don't need `split`, if you use backticks, because it will come back as a list.
- I don't think `[L|l]` means what you think it means. If you just mean a capital "L" or a lowercase "l", the alternation symbol is not needed. The proper expression is `[Ll]` ( or `(?i:l)ib` which means that we localize the i-flag for the group.)

So if it looks like this:

```
 use File::Basename; 

 my @dirs = grep { fileparse($_) =~ /^[Ll]ib/ } qx{dir /AD /B /S e:\\};
```

That should work, if there is *anything* that matches that. Just make sure that you use the `qx` operator or backticks.

Comment: +1 but you missed the possibility of a different `dir` program in `%PATH%`.